# NEWBIE can I use my own SFSafariViewController and preload a url. Then use it on storyboard

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7.2

I am trying to designate on a storyboard a UIViewController as my own custom class SimpleSafariViewController.  The compiler won't let me override init() method to preload http://news.google.com

Compile error is "Override of init method is unavailable"
If the compiler allowed me, I would have the following code

```
SimpleSafariViewController
    convenience init() {
        super.init(URL: URL("http://news.google.com"), entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
    }
```

If so, then is there another way of solving this.

I have posted the simplest project on github

https://github.com/joshuacalloway/SimpleSafari

swift 2.1, xcode 7.2

Answer (score 0):

You are not using SFSafariViewController like suggested to do so. It is not meant to sit as a ViewController on your StoryBoard. The implementation in `SuggestedSafariViewController` is the correct way to do it. (Agree with @matt)

Comment: Why is it not meant to sit on Storyboard?